# How to match IAP with a purchase entry in iTunesConnect Sales report?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

To track user Purchases we currently save all user receipts to our backend. The problem is that to get this data, user has to first launch the app. But it's very possible that user will cancel his subscription without opening the app.

So my question is does any field in Sales Report corresponds to any field in IAP receipt (it seems that there is only transactionIdentifier)? I need it for regular IAP and Subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem working on an app which offered subscriptions for cloud data storage.  The short answer is, no -- there's no way to tell if a subscription is cancelled without the user opening the app. Normally, this isn't a problem -- the point of an IAP subscription is to grant access to content in the app.  If the subscription expires, the user doesn't have access the next time they open the app.

In our case, since we were charging for continued data storage, it means a user could potentially leave data sitting on our server without paying for it.  We decided we could live with this limitation -- we took the calculated risk that active users wouldn't let their subscriptions expire, and the cost of maintaining lapsed subscriptions for inactive users was minimal.  (and as per our license, we could delete data of inactive users if we really needed to)

Another option would be a backend process which periodically prompts the user to open the app via e-mail or maybe a notification. I have no idea if Apple allows this -- didn't try it.

In general, it seems like IAP subscriptions aren't really intended for this purpose.  You kinda just have to live with the limitations...